# After downloading the entire Bitcoiin blockchain from a torrent, what are my next steps to link it to Bitcoin Core 0.17.1?

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, bitcoin-qt-setup

I downloaded the entire bitcoiin blockchain into my external mounted drive as seen below and named the directory bcore.

I then did a symlink to that folder like this in my home folder (~) location :

ln -s /mnt/xxxx/bcore .bitcoin

I then ran .bitcoind, but I thought I downloaded the entire blockchain. How do I know if its just syncing with what I already downloaded or is it literally downloading everything again? Is there a way to just skip verifying blocks if that is what it is doing. I don't have the time to wait hours for this since I already waited 23 hours to download the blockchain already.

Is there a file I can just download where it skips the block verification?

Also another reason why I think its downloading it again is because when i run bitcoin-qt on the bottom it says: "Syncing with Network" Which leaves me a bit confused.

[image]

Comment: Your story is a bit confusing: if you got the software (executable) from the torrent then you're likely running malware and you should stop, delete everything, and make sure you get the software from bitcoincore.org and verify that download. If you already got the software from there and the torrent only had data files then you should be ok and only need to be patient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no general purpose to using a torrent?
Dude have you ever tried to download the blockchain it takes ages, at first it goes fast for 2 days then it slows down to 0,03% speed per hours (mean weeks/months to complete) its innacceptable that this takes so long.

Nobody in the right mind will wait 1,5-2 Months to download it.
I wanted to support the network with a full node since i see the danger of all people using only smartphone+light nodes will break the hole idea of dectralized cryptocurrecies.

If torrent works then the Developers should copy some torrent libaries and put them into the clients to fix the download problem.

Answer (score 9):

You should not use a torrent to download the blockchain.  There is no general purpose to using a torrent, as using it makes synchronization slower because validation (which is the slow part) cannot proceed concurrently with download.  Because there is no purpose to using a torrent, I wouldn't trust that any particular torrent wasn't made maliciously and didn't contain things that might be used to exploit your computer.

Comment: so your saying just sync it directly with bitcoin core software itself? will download be slower? do I just delete the blocks/ folder and it will resync from the beginning or do I have to delete other files too?

Comment: Since Bitcoin Core v0.10 it is generally faster to just let it sync from the network itself than downloading it otherwise yourself.